# image transferred with wrong mime type?

Tags: jquery, image, apache, ubuntu, mime

When I insert an image using jquery, I get this message in console.

Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html:

http://login.mysite.se/sign/web/mp/mattias

Is my webserver not set up correctly?

Comment: Yes, your webserver is not set up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web site is telling the browser that an image is the wrong MIME type.  Yes, this is a configuration error on your web server.